# Query to list all indexes under the same table which reference the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I would like a query which would help me find all tables which have columns indexed twice. I have already found a statement which lists all indexes with their respective columns and types but I'm not able to amend it to achieve my goal:

```
select i.[name] as index_name,
    substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [columns],
    case when i.[type] = 1 then 'Clustered index'
        when i.[type] = 2 then 'Nonclustered unique index'
        when i.[type] = 3 then 'XML index'
        when i.[type] = 4 then 'Spatial index'
        when i.[type] = 5 then 'Clustered columnstore index'
        when i.[type] = 6 then 'Nonclustered columnstore index'
        when i.[type] = 7 then 'Nonclustered hash index'
        end as index_type,
    case when i.is_unique = 1 then 'Unique'
        else 'Not unique' end as [unique],
    schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view, 
    case when t.[type] = 'U' then 'Table'
        when t.[type] = 'V' then 'View'
        end as [object_type]
from sys.objects t
    inner join sys.indexes i
        on t.object_id = i.object_id
    cross apply (select col.[name] + ', '
                    from sys.index_columns ic
                        inner join sys.columns col
                            on ic.object_id = col.object_id
                            and ic.column_id = col.column_id
                    where ic.object_id = t.object_id
                        and ic.index_id = i.index_id
                            order by key_ordinal
                            for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
where t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
and index_id > 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you want just the table name, or with the relevant columns aggregated together? And do you care if the column is in a different position in the index key and whether it is an `include`?

Comment: I believe that you are looking for indexes have the same ordered list of columns.  For example:   col1, col2. does not address the same access pattern as as col2, col1.  But, col1, col2, col3 will address the same access pattern as in index of col1, col2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at the overly simplified approach that if a COLUMN exists in one INDEX then it doesn't need to exist in another INDEX, then your approach is just wrong.

If you are using this as a starting point to see if COLUMNs are used in more than one INDEX and then further analysing the INDEXes to see if you can consolidate or remove some of them, then this could be valid.

I'd suggest simplifying the initial part to get the relevant INDEX COLUMNS.  Start with :

```
SELECT object_id, column_id, COUNT(*)
FROM sys.index_columns 
GROUP BY object_id, column_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will identify all the INDEX and COLUMN combinations where the COLUMN exists more than once.  Use this as a derived table and JOIN your other tables to it to get actual object, index and column names.